# Windows search can't find .lvm-files? (files created by Native Instruments' LabView)

Tags: windows, search, file-types

I have gotten several files for several kinds of measurements. They were generated by some [ADC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog-to-digital_converter) (specific type does not matter) and the necessary software [Labview](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Labview), which are both made by Native Instruments. The files are of the type `.lvm`. Opening them with Excel is no problem, I processed them as I deemed necessary. So I had no problem there so far.

But I can't find them via Windows search. This makes cleaning them up/sorting them and other stuff rather tedious. :/ Does anyone know how I can enable Windows to find them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all file types are enabled by default. However it is simple to change this.

1. Click on the Start button, type `Indexing` and select "Indexing Options"
2. Click on "Advanced" (this may trigger UAC)
3. Click on the "File Types" tab, search for the file type you want and make sure the tickbox next to it is selected
4. Click on "Ok" and then "Close".

If you're not prepared to wait for Windows to find all those files (which, depending on how many you have, may take a while), then you can force a re-index by not performing step 4 and clicking on "Rebuild" instead.

Be warned though that this could also take a long time as you are essentially deleting the entire database and rebuilding it from scratch. Personally, I'd just leave the computer idle for a couple of hours and let Windows find those files as it would normally.

Comment: Ah, wow, has been quite some time since I visited the indexing options. Anyway, it was selected. I suppose I have to wait some time then. If this is true, I'll come back and mark this reply as the solution.